# How to extract image channels OpenCV

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv

I'm looking to change the below Matlab code to OpenCV. How can I use 'Split' to perform this?

Can I just cut and paste the 'for' loop as is?

```
L = lab(:,:,1);
a = lab(:,:,2);
b = lab(:,:,3);

[a1, b1] = size(a);

for row=1:a1
    for col=1:b1
        if ((a(row,col) <-0.196) && (a(row,col)>-0.3529) && (b(row,col)>0.1568) && (b(row,col)<0.392))
            II(row,col) = 1 ;
        else
            II(row,col) = 0 ;
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Which OpenCV interface? Python or C++?

Comment: C++ is the interface

Answer (score 4):

you can use the [split](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#split) function

```
    cv::Mat bgrImage = imread("C:/temp/cool_cat.jpg");
    cv::Mat labImage;
    cvtColor(bgrImage, labImage, CV_BGR2Lab);
    //split the channels
    vector<cv::Mat> lab_channels;
    cv::split(labImage, lab_channels);

    //verbose indexes for split LAB channels
    const int L = 0; 
    const int A = 1; 
    const int B = 2;

    //nicer than for loop IMHO
    cv::Mat_<bool> t1a,t2a,t1b, t2b;
    t1a = lab_channels[A] < 200;
    t2a = lab_channels[A] > 100;
    t1b = lab_channels[B] < 200;
    t2b = lab_channels[B] > 100;

    cv:Mat_<bool> II = t1a & t2a & t1b & t2b;
```

[cool cat image](http://1hdwallpapers.com/cool_cat-wallpaper.html)

Comment: Thanks. Can you clarify the int l = 0; int a = 1; int b = 2 line?

Comment: Hi, they are just indexes into the L, A, and B channels. Thought it looked nicer to have them as named variables. (probably should be const)

Answer (score 0):

The snippet below should get you close:

```
  vector<Mat> channels;

  split(lab, channels);

  Mat II(lab.size(), CV_8UC1);

  Mat a(channels[1]);
  Mat b(channels[2]);

  for (int r=0;r<lab.rows;r++)
    for (int c=0;c<lab.cols;c++)
      {
        if ((a.at<float>(r,c) < -0.196f) && 
            (a.at<float>(r,c)> -0.3529f) && 
            (b.at<float>(r,c) > 0.1568f) &&
            (b.at<float>(r,c) < 0.392f) ) {
            II.at<uchar>(r,c) = 255;
         } else {
            II.at<uchar>(r,c) = 0 ;
         }
      }
```

Note there are lots of assumptions that accompany this snippet:

1. Your Lab image appears to be stored in a floating point format, we'll assume CV_32FC3 for this exercise.  But take a look at the [cvtColor](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor) reference because you may run into issues with scale (note that the converted Lab format may have an offset of 128, depending on how you obtained your Lab image).
2. You might want to review the basics of channel splitting.  [This link](http://compvisionlab.wordpress.com/2013/03/07/opencv-basics-splitting-rgb-channels/) demonstrates an RGB channel split, but the same process holds true for an Lab split.
3. There are also a number of build environment assumptions: the above snippet compiles/runs under GCC 4.7.2 and OpenCV 2.4.8.  Some conveniences have been taken with namespace inclusions to simplify the snippet.

Comment: @Shai, if you edit the post, at least put the open braces in consistent positions (compare the brace for the for loop to your edits on the if and else).  Likewise, the spacing in the comparisons should be consistent.

Comment: noted. However, what triggered my edit was the use of `and` instead of `&&` in your code. You can edit my edit if you wish.

Comment: @shai, as I'm sure you are aware, *and* and *or* are valid logical operators under gcc extensions.